# find all functions $ f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ such that : $ f(f(x))=x^2-2 $

Tags: contest-math, functional-equations

This is a very hard functional equation.

the problem is this :

find all functions $ f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ such that : $ f(f(x))=x^2-2 $

to solve it i have no idea! can we solve it with highschool olympiad education?

please help : )

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/832792/if-f-is-a-strictly-increasing-function-with-ffx-x22-then-f3#comment1719142_832792

Comment: Well, $f$ cannot be injective, surjective, or weakly monotone increasing, for these sets of functions are closed under composition. Also, $f$ cannot be a polynomial by degree arguments.

Comment: @Dr.AKA You should look at the answers there.

Comment: Yes, there is the sesquicentennial [solution of Schroeder](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/208996/362193).

Answer (score 2):

As shown by Gottfried Helms in a linked question, a solution over $[-1,1]$ is given by a function defined over $(-2,+\infty)$:
$$ 2\cdot T_{\sqrt{2}}(x/2) $$
where $T_n$ is a solution to the Chebyshev differential equation 
$$ (1-x^2)\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2}-x\frac{dy}{dx}+ n^2 y = 0.$$
The first terms of the Taylor series in zero are:
$$2 \cos\left(\frac{\pi }{\sqrt{2}}\right)+\sqrt{2}\,\sin\left(\frac{\pi }{\sqrt{2}}\right) x-\frac{1}{2} \cos\left(\frac{\pi }{\sqrt{2}}\right) x^2-\frac{1}{12\sqrt{2}}\sin\left(\frac{\pi }{\sqrt{2}}\right) x^3-\frac{1}{48} \cos\left(\frac{\pi }{\sqrt{2}}\right) x^4+\ldots$$

Comment: I don't understand, on the duplicate question, the answer said that there is no such $f$, does I miss something ?

Comment: Nah, at the high-school level you can explicitly verify [362193](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2305794/362193) works. It was discovered in 1870 by Ernst Schroeder.